# How to use background image inside CSS for wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I'm using the wicked_pdf plugin with a rails 3.0 project. I want to define background with image inside css file.

Here is my css code

```
.thumb-image {
    background: url(http://localhost:3000/images/pdf/ideathumbbg.png) no-repeat left top;
    width: 1979px;
    height: 946px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 54px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

This does not find the ideathumbbg.png and it does render ideathumbbg.png in the pdf generated.

Is it possible to use the wicked_pdf_image_tag helper inside a css file? or any other best solution for this problem?

Comment: Is there any single quotes for your image url

Comment: No there is no single quotes for image URL

Comment: you must be getting some error in your logs can you check that what exact url rails is trying to access.... you must see something as rendering http://localhost:3000/images/pdf/ideathumbbg.png

Comment: Yes i have checked URL and if I copy that URL and render in browser it showing me that image. Also I have checked log for error but there is no error in log. setting background images through css in wicked_pdf is painfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wkhtmltopdf cannot render png or gif images as backgrounds:

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=544

Try converting your background image to a jpg.

Comment: Thanks Unixmonkey, I have tried this with jgp image but still doesn't work

Comment: suggestion: Have you solved your problem, then please post your solution and mark it as correct answer

Comment: Hi Ross, The solution above mentioned by Unixmonkey not worked for me.

Comment: @Sunny Try specifying it with a screen media type, or !important, or maybe changing your wkhtmltopdf binary version. I know there are some versions it doesn't work with (Check the google code site for wkhtmltopdf issues).

Comment: You are right Unixmonkey, I have tried this on wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9 version which is stable according some post. and using screen media type could you please explain in detail how to do that that will really good help for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using the SASS [asset-data-urlrelative-asset-path](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#asset-data-urlrelative-asset-path), maybe you can use something like this:

```
background-image: asset-data-url('ideathumbbg.png')
```