# wicked_pdf css background image not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I'm using wicked_pdf in Ruby-on-Rails to generate a PDF and I want to set a background image on the body element. I've linked a stylesheet with `stylesheet_link_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64("pdf.css")` and now I want to import the image as base64 (linking to the image file to save looking at the code inline).

Sass code:

```
body
  background: asset-url('pdf-background.png')
```

It works in debug mode but not rendered as a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

```
body
  background: asset-data-url('pdf-background.png')
```

Thanks to @pbrueske https://stackoverflow.com/a/30187719/203915